# How do I add calculations to my GUI in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, compiler-errors

This is my first time using Windows Forms on Visual Studio with C#. I am trying to make my form have a button where when you click "Calculate Amount Due" that it will put what was calculated into the "Amount Due" field. But, anytime I say "textBox3 = aOrder.AmountDue()", it says it can not convert double to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox. How do I convert this appropriately? Here is my code for the program.

```
namespace MidTermPizzas
{
   class pizzaOrder
   {
      public int numberOfCokes
      {
         get
         {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
         }
         set
         {
         }
      }

      public int numberOfPizzas
      {
         get
         {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
         }
         set
         {
         }
      }

      public double InputOrder()
      {
         const double COKE_PRICE = 1.49;
         const double PIZZA_PRICE = 7.99;
         double inputOrder = (numberOfCokes * COKE_PRICE) + (numberOfPizzas * PIZZA_PRICE);
         return InputOrder();
      }

      public double TaxDue()
      {
         const double TAX = .073;
         double taxDue = (this.InputOrder() * TAX);
         return TaxDue();
      }

      public double GetAmountDue()
      {
         double getAmountDue = this.InputOrder() + this.TaxDue();
         return GetAmountDue();
      }

      public double GetAmountPaid()
      {
         double getAmountPaid;
         return GetAmountPaid();
      }

      public double GetChargeDue()
      {
         double getChargeDue = this.GetAmountDue() - this.GetAmountPaid();
         return GetAmountPaid();
      }
   }
}

namespace MidTermPizzas
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      pizzaOrder aOrder = new pizzaOrder();
      DailySummary aSummary = new DailySummary();

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      //click File, Exit
      private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Enjoy your pizza!");
         this.Close();
      }

      //click View, All Orders Placed
      private void allOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         AllOrdersPlaced myForm = new AllOrdersPlaced();
         myForm.Show();
      }

      //click View, Summary of Orders Placed
      private void summaryOfOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         SummaryOfOrdersPlaced myForm2 = new SummaryOfOrdersPlaced();
         myForm2.Show();
      }

      //text in box to the right of "Amount Due"
      private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         textBox3 = aOrder.GetAmountDue();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(aOrder.AmountDue());
```

Assuming AmountDue() is returning a Double.

You had two problems, you were trying to set the actual textbox object to a string instead of the .Text property of the textbox, and you aren't converting the double to a string.

Answer (score 1):

`textBox3` is the object. The object has various methods (to do stuff) and properties (to hold stuff), specifically `textBox3.Text` which is where you can set the text in the box. Remember [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) is your friend.

Comment: "'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: C# is case sensitive, you have to use ".Text" not ".text".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, it's necessary assign the value Order.GetAmountDue() for Text property. This property contains the value of TextBox:

`textBox3.Text = aOrder.GetAmountDue();`

Because it's necessary keep the compatibility between the types, so you can't assign a `Double` for a `TextBox`, but you can assign a `Double` to a `string` (in this case the `Text` property its a `string`).

Maybe you need format the value, for more information see this link:
[Double.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Textbox issue, I also don't think you should be returning the public method itself.ie
instead of

```
 public double TaxDue()
        {
            const double TAX = .073;
            double taxDue = (this.InputOrder() * TAX);
            return TaxDue();
        }
```

You should have

```
 public double TaxDue()
        {
            const double TAX = .073;
            double taxDue = (this.InputOrder() * TAX);
            return taxDue;
        }
```

The first implementation doesn't make sense.